# Google Cloud ML using Rest API

Tags: google-cloud-ml, google-cloud-ml-engine

Can any one help me how to access google cloud ml service using Rest API in python. I have tried it using postman but it gives 404 in response everytime.I have some project  on google cloud I just want to use all the apis available on https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/reference/rest/

Comment: Can you provide some more details about how you are calling the service; a code snippet would be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

You can find examples from Datalab:

Training service:
https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/blob/master/google/datalab/ml/_job.py#L61

Prediction service:
https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/blob/master/google/datalab/ml/_cloud_models.py#L225

Alternatively, instead of calling CloudML service endpoints directly, you can try Datalab's ml toolbox itself which supports structured data and image classification. You can view the notebooks first without setting up datalab:

https://github.com/googledatalab/notebooks/tree/master/samples/ML%20Toolbox

To set up Datalab and actually run these notebooks, see https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/quickstarts.